# C# / XML / Parsing / comparing file locations saved by different programs, one using localhost in the uri

Tags: c#, xml, file, location, uri

I'm parsing XML files written by different programs, both using a different way to store a file location.
I want to compare to see if these locations resolve to the same file.

These are the two ways the location is stored:

file://localhost/C:/Users/Stackoverflow/test.mp3

file:///C:/Users/Stackoverflow/test.mp3

I could ofcourse just remove the "file:///" and "file://localhost/" parts, but I'm wondering if there is a more "proper" C# way to resolve these locations and see if they match?

Comment: Just trim ‘localhost’ and compare.

Comment: If you only are going to compare once then I would use a tool like Beyond Compare to compare the folders.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any need to get fancy here. Just remove the `file:///` and `file://localhost/` parts and compare the resulting strings.